# Is there a way to test if flask template contains a link?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, testing, flask

I've been testing whether routes exist using

```
def test_index(self):
    r = self.app.get("/")
    self.assertEqual(200, r.status_code, "Status code was not 'OK'.")
```

My template has a hyperlink to another page. Is there a way to test if this exists?

Comment: Do you make your links using `url_for()`?

Comment: Yes, I use url_for()

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are testing templates, every template you render is the result of a request to some route. If you render url's in a template using `url_for()`, then it will raise a `BuildError` if the url is pointing to a non existing route, and the server will return the status code 500. Therefore, you don't need to parse your templates manually for testing purposes if you just check the route instead.

Example:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template_string("""
        {{ url_for('index') }}
        {{ url_for('blabla') }}
    """)


def test_index(self):
    r = self.app.get("/index")
    self.assertEqual(200, r.status_code, "Status code was not 'OK'.")
```

This will result in a 
`routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'blabla'. Did you mean 'static' instead?` error, which makes your tests fail.

I hope this explanation is clear enough!